# Linq to Entities group by week number

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am using ASP.NET v4.5 and linq to entities
I am trying to group my data by week using the below code

```
var groupedByWeek = salesOrdersList
    .GroupBy(i => i.DueDate.AddDays(-(int)i.DueDate.DayOfWeek));
```

However I am getting a "yellow screen of death" with the error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime AddDays(Double)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Ideally I would like to put

```
var groupedByWeek = salesOrdersList.GroupBy(i => i.DueDate.WeekNumber);
```

But life isn't that easy!

Does anyone know a way of using week numbers with Linq to Entities?

Comment: What's the problem with it?

Comment: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime AddDays(Double)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: What happens if you change it to `i => i.DueDate - TimeSpan.FromDays(i.DueDate.DayOfWeek)` or `i => i.DueDate - new TimeSpan(i.DueDate.DayOfWeek, 0, 0, 0)`?

Comment: system.DayOfWeek is not assignable to parameter type Double

Comment: (slaps forehead) with that im still getting LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.TimeSpan FromDays(Double)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: And what about the second suggestion? My comment contained two possible alternatives.

Comment: The second suggestion gave "Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities."

Comment: Meh... In that case, try the answer by Marcin.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [`SqlFunctions.DatePart()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487171.aspx) method:

```
var groupedByWeek = salesOrdersList.GroupBy(i => SqlFunctions.DatePart("week", i.DueDate));
```

It will add `DATEPART` sql function call into generated SQL query.

Answer (score 2):

For daily:

```
var daily = salesOrdersList.Where(x => (long)(x.DueDate - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)).TotalDays == (long)(Datetime.Now.ToLocalTime()- new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)).TotalDays ).ToList();
```

OR

```
var daily = salesOrdersList.Where(x => x.DueDate.Day == Datetime.Now.ToLocalTime().Day).ToList();
```

For Weekly:

```
var weekly = salesOrdersList.Where(x => (long)(x.DueDate - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)).TotalDays / 7 == (long)(Datetime.Now.ToLocalTime()- new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)).TotalDays / 7).ToList();
```

For Monthly

```
var monthly= salesOrdersList.Where(x => x.DueDate.Month== Datetime.Now.ToLocalTime().Month).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can get the date of the first day in the week then group by that date.

To get the date of the first day in the week.
you can use this code:

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static DateTime StartOfWeek(this DateTime dt, DayOfWeek startOfWeek)
    {
        int diff = dt.DayOfWeek - startOfWeek;
        if (diff < 0)
        {
            diff += 7;
        }
        return dt.AddDays(-1 * diff).Date;
    }
}
```

then you can group by the first date of the week like this:

```
var groupedByWeek = salesOrdersList.GroupBy(i => i.DueDate.StartOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Monday));
```

Comment: Hmm I like this solution but I get this err:r System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime StartOfWeek(System.DateTime, System.DayOfWeek)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Yes, you are right.
I think the  solution for this is by using `SqlFunctions`
Like @MarcinJuraszek's solution :
`var groupedByWeek = salesOrdersList.GroupBy(i => SqlFunctions.DatePart("week", i.DueDate));`
because this function can be translate to this regular SQL code
`SELECT * From T GROUP BY DATEPART(wk, T.Date)`