# LINQ - GroupBy Year/Month

Tags: c#, linq, charts, group-by

I'm trying to populate graph data with total amount(sum) by a last four months, and visually it would look like this:

[image]

I've tried so far to group data by year and by a month, but I'm not sure if it's right approach cuz this doesn't work..

Here is the code:

```
 var testQUERY = await _context.Calculation
             .AsNoTracking()
             .Where(x => (x.PaymentDate != null && x.PaymentDate > DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(-4)))
            .GroupBy(x => new { x.PaymentDate.Value.Year, x.PaymentDate.Value.Month}).ToListAsync();
```

Here's my paymentDate :
[image]

And I'm wondering how could I group by month only.. 
Error I'm facing is next:

> Error generated for warning
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryClientEvaluationWarning: The
>   LINQ expression 'GroupBy(new <>f__AnonymousType0`2(Year =
>   Convert([p].PaymentDate, DateTime).Year, Month =
>   Convert([p].PaymentDate, DateTime).Month), [p])' could not be
>   translated and will be evaluated locally.'. This exception can be
>   suppressed or logged by passing event ID
>   'RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning' to the
>   'ConfigureWarnings' method in 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' or
>   'AddDbContext'.

P.S If I better think because I'm using

```
x.PaymentDate != null && x.PaymentDate > DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(-4)
```

I don't need new anonymous type where I included year also.. but obliviusly I'm trying to group by column which does not exist.. ?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45237492/ef-core-could-not-be-translated-and-will-be-evaluated-locally ?

Comment: @dfhwze I'm not sure how this solvs my issue ?

Comment: your issue can be solved by materialising the results using _ToList()_ or something and then perform the grouping

Comment: @dfhwze isn't it the same if I apply groupBy directly on a data which I'm getting from DB or if I store it to some variable and than apply groupBy to the same data..

Comment: it all depends what the LINQ to EF provider is able to map from LNQ to query. It appears not all GroupBy constructs are translatable.

Comment: Your query looks reasonable. Be careful, as no PaymentDate will change. You should be looking at key of the grouping to see year/month value. As for the error, I would guess the problem is accessing of value. Maybe try selecting the non-null values in separate select?

Comment: @Euphoric Separate select solvs it, but what about key of the grouping? Could you please write me an example ?

Comment: Another thing that comes to mind is that you should have a Select after the GroupBy where you flatten the groups by calculating the aggregates.

Comment: @Euphoric Could you post an answer with keys included and little explanation about why would you include it and why it's safer? So I can accept it as an answer, thanks!

Comment: @Euphoric I'm confused also how can I get Jan, Feb, March as a string values or even 1, 2, 3, so I can later match 1, 2, 3, with strings Jan, Feb, March.. Thanks man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this one. See comments for possible fixes.

```
var testQUERY = await _context.Calculation
         .AsNoTracking()
         .Where(x => x.PaymentDate != null)
         .Select(x => new { PaymentDate = x.PaymentDate.Value, Row=x }) // pre-select non-null payment date
         .Where(x => x.PaymentDate > DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(-4)) // this should go after the grouping, as it might include from just part of the month
         .GroupBy(x => new { x.PaymentDate.Year, x.PaymentDate.Month})
         .Select(grp=> new { grp.Key.Year, grp.Key.Month, Count = grp.Count()) // flatten group and calculate aggregates
         .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: @Euphoris thanks a lot vote up! While you are here, how would look grouping by a week for example for each month in this 4 month I would like to return 4 weeks for example for 4 month there would be 16 weeks with sum by week :D ? :)

Comment: @Roxy'Pro Here is inspiration : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15969174/linq-to-entities-group-by-week-number

Comment: not sure how to apply this to my example.. :/ There's link to my question above in a comment

Comment: @Roxy'Pro I'm sorry, but the solution is obvious to me. You are clearly not even trying to understand the link I sent you. I would really recommend you to look at some basic tutorials about LINQ-to-Entities.